# I cannot add "AWS": "*" in my cloudformation code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

I have a simple cloudformation which creates a bucket with policy attached to it. Here is the cloud formation code I have:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: testforcfn
    DeletionPolicy: Retain

  BucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Id: MyPolicy
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Sid: PublicReadForGetBucketObjects
          Effect: Allow
          Principal: "*"
          Action: s3:GetObject
          Resource:
            Fn::Join:
            - ''
            - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
              - Ref: S3Bucket
              - "/*"
      Bucket:
         Ref: S3Bucket
Outputs:
  S3Info:
    Value:
        Ref: S3Bucket
```

Everything works fine, however, in the bucket policy in the principal, instead of "*" I need "AWS": "*". So for more explanation here is the bucket policy I want to have:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1506624486110",
    "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "Stmt1506624421375",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testforcfn/*"
    }]
}
```

So this part is what I want to have in my cloudformation code :

```
       "Principal": {
           "AWS": "*"
       }
```

When I do this in my cloudformation I get an error:

```
              Principal: "AWS:*"
```

Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: What error do you see? FYI "Principal": "*" is equivalent to "Principal" : { "AWS" : "*" }.

Comment: Actually I deleted the stack and forgot to capture the exact error but basically it says one of the resources failed to create and nothing specific bit I am sure it is because of this :  Principal: "AWS:*" because when I do this it works :  Principal: "*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
Principal: 
  AWS: "*"
```

You can find a relevant example [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-iam.html#quickref-iam-example-8.yaml).